Deserialize json using jackson
So, I'm using this class to deserialize the json:
public class DataConverter implements IDataConverter {
    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public <T> T getData(String json, Class<T> classe) {
        try {
            var result = mapper.readValue(json, classe);
            System.out.println();
            return result;
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}


It works fine with normal json's but when I have a json that contains arrays[] it always returns null to the class, so how can I access those array with jackson keeping it generic so I can use other types of class.
This is the json I'm trying to deserialize:
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 55752,
            "title": "Dom Casmurro",
            "authors": [
                {
                    "name": "Machado de Assis",
                    "birth_year": 1839,
                    "death_year": 1908
                }
            ],
            "translators": [],
            "subjects": [
                "Adultery -- Fiction",
                "Authorship -- Fiction",
                "Catholic Church -- Fiction",
                "Reminiscing in old age -- Fiction"
            ],
            "bookshelves": [],
            "languages": [
                "pt"
            ],
            "copyright": false,
            "media_type": "Text",
            "formats": {
                "text/plain; charset=us-ascii": "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/55752.txt.utf-8",
                "text/html": "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/55752.html.images",
                "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1": "https://www.gutenberg.org/files/55752/55752-h/55752-h.htm",
                "application/epub+zip": "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/55752.epub3.images",
                "application/x-mobipocket-ebook": "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/55752.kf8.images",
                "text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1": "https://www.gutenberg.org/files/55752/55752-8.txt",
                "application/rdf+xml": "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/55752.rdf",
                "image/jpeg": "https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/55752/pg55752.cover.medium.jpg",
                "application/octet-stream": "https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/55752/pg55752-h.zip"
            },
            "download_count": 915
        }
    ]
}

the main class:
public class Main {
    private ApiRequest request = new ApiRequest();
    private DataConverter conversor = new DataConverter();
    public void principal(){
        var test = request.consumo("https://gutendex.com/books?search=dom%20casmurro");
        Author author = new Author(conversor.getData(test, AuthorData.class));
        System.out.println(author);
    }
}

and a record used for jackson
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public record AuthorData(@JsonAlias("name")String nomeDoAutor,
                         @JsonAlias("birth_year") Integer anoDeNascimento,
                         @JsonAlias("death_year") Integer anoDeFalecimento) {
}

and the author class:
public class Author {
    private String name;
    private Integer anoDeNascimento;
    private Integer anoDeFalecimento;

    public Author(AuthorData data) {
        this.name = data.nomeDoAutor();
        this.anoDeNascimento = data.anoDeNascimento();
        this.anoDeFalecimento = data.anoDeFalecimento();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAnoDeNascimento() {
        return anoDeNascimento;
    }

    public void setAnoDeNascimento(Integer anoDeNascimento) {
        this.anoDeNascimento = anoDeNascimento;
    }

    public Integer getAnoDeFalecimento() {
        return anoDeFalecimento;
    }

    public void setAnoDeFalecimento(Integer anoDeFalecimento) {
        this.anoDeFalecimento = anoDeFalecimento;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name: " + name +
                "\nanoDeNascimento: " + anoDeNascimento +
                "\nanoDeFalecimento: " + anoDeFalecimento;
    }
}


The question is lacking details right now. Please post your Class you want the json to be converted to and how you call the conversion. Basically a full reproducible example. The getData method looks fine to me.

i just added a few more details

Either the JSON is not what you expect it to be or the code you pasted does not fit your result. The class you use to call jackson should be a presentation of the full json. I would expect your model to look like @Vinayak Nair `s answer or jackson will throw an Exception.

the DataConverter class is using generic info so i could pass any class to it, and with normal json works just fine, but when i have a json with arrays the class cant get the attributes cause they are inside of arrays. so that is my question the only attributes i want from the whole json is the "name", "birth_year" and "death_year" what is the easiest way to get them with jackson keeping it generic

In your entity class, map list of results as:
public Class ExampleJson {    
 int count;
 String next;
 String previous;
 List<Results> results;
 .....
}

